# Why the button area is not working as I expected?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an auto scroll tool for the browser(Chrome). What i want is a button, so when i click the button, the page should auto scroll down. By the way, I am using an application, whenever i visit a website, the application will inject the script below in the website. Here is my script:

```js
<script>
let btn = document.createElement("button"); 
var isScrolling = false; 
btn.innerHTML = "start scroll"; 
btn.style.cssText = "width:50px;height:50px;float:right;background:grey;position:fixed;right:0;top:50%;opacity:0.5;border-radius:50%"
btn.addEventListener("click", () => onclick); 
let autoScroll = () => {if(isScrolling){window.scrollBy(0, 1);setTimeout(autoScroll, 10)}};
onclick = function() {console.log("click"); isScrolling=!isScrolling; autoScroll()}; 
document.body.appendChild(btn); 
</script>
```

The problem is when I click the other areas of the page(not the button area), it still will trigger the onclick function. What i want is the page only scroll down when i click the button area, not any other area of the page. Does anyone know where the problem is? You can copy and run the script in the chrome console, any help would appreciate!

Comment: If I create a web page and paste your script at the end of the body it works as expected

Comment: Your `onclick` definition lacks a `let` or `var` so it becomes global and may conflict with other scripts on the page. Also, `() => onclick` won't really do anything (it will return the function when clicked, but won't execute the function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing your onclick function into a global one, because you are not defining it before. This works correctly:

```
<script>
let btn = document.createElement("button"); 
var isScrolling = false;
const onclick = function() {console.log("click"); isScrolling=!isScrolling; autoScroll()};  
btn.innerHTML = "start scroll"; 
btn.style.cssText = "width:50px;height:50px;float:right;background:grey;position:fixed;right:0;top:50%;opacity:0.5;border-radius:50%"
btn.addEventListener("click", onclick); 
let autoScroll = () => {if(isScrolling){window.scrollBy(0, 1);setTimeout(autoScroll, 10)}};
document.body.appendChild(btn); 
</script>
```

Pay attention that i'm defining the onclick before using it, and that it is directly used in addEventListener, you shouldn't return it in the arrow function:

```
// This is WRONG
btn.addEventListener("click", () => onclick);
// This is OK
btn.addEventListener("click", onclick);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are running into conflicts with your variables and the scripts already on the page. If injecting this script, you can break javascript code already on the page.

To get the variables into their own frame, try this:

```
<script>
(function () {
    let btn = document.createElement("button"); 
    var isScrolling = false; 
    btn.innerHTML = "start scroll"; 
    btn.style.cssText = 
"width:50px;height:50px;float:right;background:grey;position:fixed;right:0;top:50%;opacity:0.5;border-radius:50%"
    let onclick = function() {console.log("click"); isScrolling=!isScrolling; autoScroll()}; 
    btn.addEventListener("click", onclick); 
    let autoScroll = () => {if(isScrolling){window.scrollBy(0, 1);
    setTimeout(autoScroll, 10)}};
    document.body.appendChild(btn); 
})();

</script>
```

Comment: I can even be simplified to `{ /* code */ }`

Comment: @A1rPun  only with `let`, not `var`.  For some reason it is using both so I left it that way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => onclick);
```

You would want either:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", onclick); // binding a reference for later execution
```

or

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => onclick());
```

However, if you want to later `btn.removeEventListener` to prevent memory leaks, you would rather want the former variant

It would also be better code if you first declared the `onclick` handler and then bound it to button, not the other way around :)

Comment: I tried both variants but the behavior is still wrong (I am trying to use it here on SO)

Comment: And there is one more mistake, the onclick function should define with let or const before using it, otherwise it will be defined as global one, this is another mistake beside the one you point out. I learned this from another answer, you can check it.